# Allow Java/1.5.0 User-Agent on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My hosting provider is blocking "Java/1.5.0" user-agent, I need to allow this user-agent on a specific folder, can I make it with an .htacces on this folder?

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "Java/1.5.0" allow_ua
order deny,allow
allow from env=allow_ua
```

is not working

Comment: That all rather depends how the existing blocking is implemented.

Comment: I have no access to apache config files :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have discover that is the ModSecurity Module who is blocking this user-agent, I have asked hosting support to revise the ModSecurity rules meanwhile I have to disable totally the ModSecurity Module in my hosting.